# Problem with heredoc inside case. Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

If in my terminal I write

```
cat <<-EOF
hello
EOF
```

I get the expected output, hello.

Now, In a script I'm writing I have

```
PARAMS=""
while (( "$#" )); do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      cat <<-EOF
      hello
      EOF
      exit 0  
      ;;
    --) # end argument parsing
      shift
      ...
```

But vscode is highlighting everything after the line `cat<<-EOF` as if it all was a string, basically ignoring the EOF.
And in fact when I run the script I get a

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

error

Edit:

if I indent the code like this:

```
while (( "$#" )); do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      cat <<EOF
      ciao
EOF
      exit 0  
      ;;
    --) # end argument parsing
      shift
      ...
```

with EOF on the left, vscode recognises it as it should, hilighting the rest of the file as a normal bash script and everithing works. But indentation-wise this sucks. Is there a way to indent EOF with the cat command?

Comment: Can you try to put a `tab` in front of EOF ?

Comment: @Philippe what's a <kbd> ?

Comment: Pretty sure the EOF has to begin the line.

Comment: with tab in front of EOF there's still the problem. It only works when EOF is at the beginning of the line like @stark says.

Comment: Make sure you have put a `tab`, from doc `If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from  in- put  lines  and  the  line  containing delimiter.  This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.` I just tested your code, it works with a `tab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -EOF has to be at the beginning of the line.  I've made that mistake several times when I prettyprint a script and inadvertently indent the heredoc terminator.

Comment: Cannot create a new answer, so i'm adding this comment. This is not the problem here... he used `<<-EOF` in which the dash means that you CAN indent the heredoc terminator... The actual problem is that you **must use TABS** when indenting the terminator (as you can see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76483/348102) and as said by @Philippe) and probably @ninazzo used spaces. Another thing is that the terminator CANNOT be followed by **any** character or it will break

Comment: Note: the original problem statement has a - in front of the EOF.  Later in the problem statement, the - is omitted.  The answer still stands that the terminator must occur at the beginning of the line (and with nothing else following it).  Indiscriminant prettyprinting of bash scripts is not a general safe practice.

Answer (score 6):

You could to use spaces before `EOF` in here-doc like this:

```
    cat <<"    EOF"
        foo
        bar
    EOF
```

But to avoid formatting/indentation issues I prefer to use functions for that:

```
print_help() {
cat <<EOF
    foo
    bar
EOF
}
...
PARAMS=""
while (( "$#" )); do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      print_help
      exit 0  
      ;;
    --) # end argument parsing
      shift
      ...
```

It also makes code cleaner.