# Shell Script to Replace or Insert Lines of Text in File

Tags: shell

I wrote a Shell script to replace text in the Jenkinsfiles of a large number of repos. I had used this to add on a parameter to a single line of text. However, now I need to insert a line of text before and after an existing command in the Jenkinsfiles. I don't have too much shell experience and could use some help.

Here is the Jenkinsfile text before:

```
sh "chmod +x increment.sh"
def result = sh returnstdout:true, script: "./increment.sh '${Version}' '${ReleaseVersion}' '${GitRepoURL}' '${CutRelease}' '${Branch}' '${JiraID}'"
//echo "$result"
```

I need to add the following before the "def result" line:

```
sshagent(['gitssh']) {
```

and then add a closing curly bracket after the "def result" line:

```
}
```

I need the end result to be:

```
sh "chmod +x increment.sh"
sshagent(['gitssh']) {
    def result = sh returnstdout:true, script: "./increment.sh '${Version}' '${ReleaseVersion}' '${GitRepoURL}' '${CutRelease}' '${Branch}' '${JiraID}'"
}
//echo "$result"
```

I actually don't care about keeping the commented out echo command if that makes it more difficult, but it is just to show what I have surrounding the "def result" line.

**How can I accomplish this end result?**

If it helps, I previously was adding new parameters at the end of the "def result" line with this code:

```
if [ -e Jenkinsfile ]
then
    sed -i -e "s/\${Branch}/\${Branch}\' \'\${JiraID}/g" Jenkinsfile
fi
```

Note: I am on a Mac.

Code so far:

```
file=repos_remaining.txt
while IFS="," read -r repoURL repoName; do
echo $repoURL
cd ..
echo $repoName
cd $(echo $repoName | tr -d '\r')
file=repos_remaining.txt    
if [ -e Jenkinsfile ]
then
    # sed -i -e $"s/def result/sshagent([\'gitssh\']) {\
    #   def result/g" Jenkinsfile
fi

# git add "Jenkinsfile"
# git commit -m "Added JiraID parameter to Jenkinsfile"
# git push origin master
done < "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

As with most cases where people want to automate the editing of a file, I suggest using `ed`:

```
ed -s Jenkinsfile <<'EOF'
/^def result/i
sshagent(['gitssh']) {
.
.+1a
}
.
w
EOF
```

The commands in the heredoc tell `ed` to move the cursor to the first line starting with `def result`, **i**nsert a line above it, **a**ppend a line after it, and finally **w**rite the modified file back to disc.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I was getting an unexpected end of file error with the line number at the end of my script, when I inserted your code inside my "then" clause. I've added my whole script to the question to provide clarity.

Comment: If I cannot get this to work, I can at least add it all in one line in the Jenkinsfile:
  sed -i -e "s/def result/sshagent([\'gitssh\']) {def result/g" Jenkinsfile;
  sed -i -e "s/\${JiraID}\'\"/\${Jira ID}\'\"}/g" Jenkinsfile;

Comment: @Coogie7 Bet you made the same mistake as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308141/problem-with-heredoc-inside-case-bash-script)